# Efficient design for a self regulating villager breeder?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

I'm playing on a SMP server and would like to begin a villager trading industry.  I've looked at lots of designs for villager breeders that can be started easily (no nearby villages, so I'll have to cure zombies) but have been unable to find one that shuts off after a certain threshold of villagers is reached.  If possible, I would like it to be fully automatic, but minimal interaction is ok.  Basically, the goal is to have a "pool" of villagers that I can draw from at any time, ensuring that when I go through many in short succession I don't have to wait for breeding.  To prevent excessive lag, this "pool" should be kept fairly small (20-40) at all times.

Comment: The max population of villagers is determined by the number of doors in the "village".  Unfortunately, since villagers take time to grow up, it's nearly impossible to always have a fresh supply.

Comment: Most designs push the villagers outside the bounds of the village, thus allowing infinite spawning with very few doors.  I was hoping for a way to limit the number, while still having a fairly high villager population and using minimal doors (thus minimizing size).

Comment: You can try to adapt one of the existing designs that have an 'off' switch - collect villagers on top of an iron pressure plate and turn off the breeder after a certain number is reached.

Comment: Ok, that would certainly work, and be very configurable towards my needs.  The problem then becomes how to toggle the breeder.  I've seen designs that cover the "outside blocks" so there are no houses recognized, but I've heard that this can cause villagers to despawn since they're not part of a village.  The other option would he simply funneling excess villagers into a kill chamber, but this could anger existing villagers, preventing them from trading.

Comment: I don't think villagers will ever despawn - even if they are not part of a village. Also villagers are angered only if you let one die within 16 block of you. Here is a very simple breeding cell: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YYyuASdoc4A&t=4m - it can be switched off by moving the two top wool blocks to the sides of the doors.

Answer (score 2):

My planned solution to this problem, when I get back to working on my villager trading system, is to have a core breeding area, that infinitely breeds.

Then, have a system that allows villagers to "escape" once the population is large.

Then, collect the "escaped" villagers, and once enough have escaped, kill the rest.

So villagers will always breed, but also, will always be killed if you AFK for long enough.

I'm having trouble finding a video that explains what I'm going to do, but in looking for one, I found DOCM's villager trading video, and in it, he explains how to set up your trading system such that you don't need infinite villagers, which may be a viable alternative to what you're wanting to do.

To do this, you need to "fill" all the villager's trading slots.  You want to get the "good" trades to be the last slot for a filled villager trading slots.  (paper -> emeralds (librarian), raw chickens -> emeralds (farmer), iron -> emeralds (blacksmith)) are all "easy" to get unlimited quantities of.  Then, once these trades are in the last slot of the villager, you can keep trading the villager for those trades, and get unlimited emeralds, without having to generate unlimited villagers.

Answer (score -1):

You can watch this video

I hope it helps you

Comment: It'd be appreciated if you could sum up the key points from the video, since YouTube videos can be known to disappear.